# Swift: How to get row number of a button in each table row?

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode6

Ive got a table. each table has its own custom button. when its pressed the following funtion runs

```
@IBAction func select(sender: UIButton) {

      anobject.itsproperty[the row?] = true
 }
```

how do I access which row the button was pressed from? so i can use that to access an array.

Answer (score 4):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`assign the row index to the `tag` property of the button.

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

then get the tag to distinguish the rows

```
@IBAction func select(sender: UIButton) {
   if sender.tag == 0 {
     // do something with first row
   }
 }
```

Comment: edited code above..  if any rows button is pressed. an objects property array gets set to true.  so its the same condition for each row.. Cant make 20 if statements?

Comment: could you please describe the structure of _objects property array_ a bit more in detail

Comment: Ive got an object, lets say  var x:Card. and x.selected=false. when button is pressed, x.selected=true.

Comment: sorry, it's not clearer. What is structure of the array you're talking about and what is the relationship between the array and the row index. Maybe you simply mean `let anObject = objectArray[sender.tag] anObject.selected = true`