# How do you get the indexpath.row when a button in a cell is tapped?

Tags: swift, uitableview

When a button in a table row cell is pressed, it will activate this function ( just print the indexrow number of the row pressed)

```
@IBAction func tickAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let button = sender as UIButton
    let view = button.superview!
    let cells = view.superview as TableViewCell

    let indexPath = TableViewController.indexPath(cells)//itemTable.indexPathForCell(cells)   <--ERROR here

    println(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: if you just need the index to access the proper element in the model array, use the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401834/swift-how-to-get-row-number-of-a-button-in-each-table-row/31402140#31402140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create a custom table view cell

2) In that class create an IBAction for button

3) Create a delegate of custom cell

4) conform to protocol in your view controller

5) set delegate in cellforRowIndexpath cell

6) now you can access button tap in delegate method

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this.

One of the most easiest is to get the location of the button tapped and look up indexPath for that point. Something like

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [buttonPressed convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```